# Getting the keywords of text classification prediction in real time

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bert, text-classification

I am using a BERT based text classification model to classify sentences/documents. My use case is like I need to highlight the words that are responsible for classification of a particular class. This has to be done in real time with minimum amount of time. I have tried using LIME for getting the words responsible for predictions but it is very slow. Kindly suggest any techniques to have that in real time or any model architecture that can predict class along with its words responsible for prediction of that particular class.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know this stuff very well, but I suspect that there's no way to probe a complex model efficiently. If you need speed, maybe traditional method like decision trees are more suitable. Hopefully somebody will give you a more useful answer.